# React useEffect: Use data not defined as parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dynamic URL that needs to be fetched using an axios call in useEffect hook.

```
const ShowData = ({country}) => {
    const [searchResult, setSearch] = useState([])
    const url = `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`
    useEffect((url) => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            setSearch(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Data data={searchResult}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When using `url` inside the useEffect hook, it says React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency. How do I use the URL inside the hook?

Comment: You don't have to pass it to your `useEffect` as a parameter as it is already declared in the upper scope.

Comment: I thought so, but it's giving me this issue: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'url'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are creating `url` based on `country`, Actually you need to pass `country` as one of useEffect dependencies and move `url` definition inside the effect body, so whenever country has changed, your effect will run. like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        setSearch(response.data)
    })
}, [country])
```

Comment: A small follow-up: If I want to make this axios call only if `country` is not null, i.e., when `country` is not `""`, how do I do this?

Comment: wrap the body inside an `if`, like this: `if(country) { // define url and axios call here }`

Comment: Glad I could help.